# Does FoF mutual fund have higher net expense ratio than advertised?

Tags: india, etf, index-fund, expense-ratio

I am looking at 2 funds. One is ETF which tracks an index. Another is Mutual Fund which invests only in the earlier ETF.

1. Mirae Asset FANG+ Index ETF FoF MF: https://groww.in/mutual-funds/mirae-asset-nyse-fang-etf-fof-direct-growth (expense ratio: 0.16%)
2. Mirae Asset FANG+ Index ETF: https://groww.in/etfs/mirae-asset-nyse-fang-etf (expense ratio 0.51%)

Q1. Will above mutual fund (2) have higher net expense ratio than 0.16% because underlying ETF also has 0.51% expense ratio?

Q2. Any other parameters to consider besides expense ratio to decide which investment is better?

Comment: I am aware that currently investment into ETF FoF is paused.

Comment: 'Which investment is better' is off-topic for this site; if you edit to more strictly align with your final sentence [other parameters to consider], and change question title to be less directive, it may become answerable'.

Comment: I have updated question to make it more generic and not an investment solicitation. Is it possible to reopen it now with updated details? @Grade'Eh'Bacon

Comment: looks answerable to me; voted to reopen.